# after effects, removing part on every frame automatically

Tags: after-effects

I have a video where somebody walks in with a shirt on with text. I want to remove the text on every frame but because the person moves and turns i am looking for a way how i can automate that. so that the program understands which part has to go and does that on every frame. Is there a way of doing this automatically?

Comment: "No" is the answer. Of course, to really know, it would require seeing the shot and how complex it is. But most likely this is a roto-every-frame-or-nearly-every-frame situation. "Roto" means using masks (or other techniques) to isolation certain areas. You can then use various methods to "remove" the offending content.

Answer (score 0):

Full automation is not likely, but a mix of automation and elbow grease might do the trick. The exact mix depends on the shot.

Motion tracking the text on the footage layer through Mocha (Animation -> Track in mocha ae) will give you position/scale/rotation data that you can then apply to a second layer with a fix implemented - a blur or color layer for example. The elbow grease comes in here, where you will most likely need to roto the fix as the person turns and the text changes shape, etc.

Again, depending on the shot it may be more elbow grease than you want. There is no alternative, however - this is the process vfx artists follow at every level of the industry.